# breadcrumb not showing in login page.i am using angular 1.5 and above version

Tags: angularjs

> Hi  i am implementing breadcrumb on login page and other angularjs html pages application.I am using angular1.5 above version.I am tring in all the way but getting the following error

angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0

Could you please anyone teach me to solve this issue so i can get the idea to solve other issues when i get.Please do give any simple example code link if you can...

```js
var app= angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ng-breadcrumbs']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider
   .when('/',{
       templateUrl:'login.html',
       controller:'loginCtrl',
       label:'login'
   })
   .when('/offers',{
       templateUrl:'home.html',
       controller:'homeCtrl'
    
   })
   .otherwise({
       redirectTo:'/'
   });
}]);
app.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope','breadcrumbs',function($scope, $location,$rootScope,breadcrumbs){
    $scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
    $scope.submit = function(){
       
       if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin'){
          $rootScope.loggedIn=true;
          $location.path('/offers');  
       }
       else{
           alert('wrong stuff');
           
       }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/js/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/js/angular-route.js"></script>
 <!-- <script src="resources/js/angular-route.js"></script> -->
 <script src="resources/js/dirPagination.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/js/angular-breadcrumb.min.js"></script>
 <!-- controller app -->
 <script src="resources/js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/js/login.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/js/home.js"></script>
 <!--Import bootstrap.css-->
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery 3_2_1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap337.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div ng-view>
      <ol class="ab-nav breadcrumb">
          <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.get() track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }">
            <a ng-if="!$last" ng-href="#{{ breadcrumb.path }}" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label" class="margin-right-xs"></a>
            <span ng-if="$last" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label"></span>
          </li>
        </ol>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: You cut off the part of the error that tells you the name

Comment: your inject arguments don't match the function.

Comment: Now you completely removed the error instead of getting the important part that even tells you which module

Comment: angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0